# Having troubles joining 3 dataframes - pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have three dataframes and I am getting an error when I join them. Here are the 3 dataframes:

Name:  r_df
Col 1:   lab_key 
Col 2:   frame

Name:  f_df
Col 1:   lab_key 
Col 2:   optic

Name:  m_df
Col 1:   lab_key 
Col 2:   res

All three dataframes have an equal number of rows of 250 and each dataframe has the same lab_keys.

My code looks like this:

```
newDF = r_df.join(f_df, r_df.lab_key == f_df.lab_key).join(m_df, r_df.lab_key == m_df.lab_key).select('r_df.frame', 'f_df.optic', 'm_df.res')
```

I get an error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o902.join.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'lab_key' is ambiguous, could be: lab_key#1648, lab_key#1954.;

Not very helpful on what the problem could be.  I am trying to get one dataframe with the columns like:

Col 1:  lab_key
Col 2:  frame
Col 3:  optic
Col 4:  res

Can you help me join these three data frames?

Comment: There is no `===` operator in Python. I do not believe you are using `join` correctly, too. Looks like R to me.

Comment: OK, my bad.  I removed the extra =.  Now I get the following:  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o902.join.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'lab_key' is ambiguous, could be: lab_key#1648, lab_key#1954.;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because pyspark dataframe created after the first join has two columns with the Exact same column name.

```
r_df.join(f_df, ["lab_key"]).join(m_df, ["lab_key"])
```

If the keys on which you are joining are the same, there's no need to specifically refer that column from the dataframe but instead just specify the name as an array. This will tell Pyspark to create only one column with that name in the final dataframe

Comment: I was aware of that duplicate columns, but I did not how I could not figure out the syntax.  Thanks, this is great!  I learned something new.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Always irritated me that there were two columns after an inner join... why?